# Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Session' not found

Tags: laravel, session

I'm new in laravel. Having problem to show session temporary flash message.
Can not rescue from this error

> Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Session' not found
>   What to do?

Comment: you can use `\Session::` instead of `Session::` or else you can import session using `user Session;` in the namespace list...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add `use Session;` to the top of the class.

Or use full namespace, like `\Session::`

Or just use the `session()` helper instead of the facade.

Answer (score 8):

Use this

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;
```

Answer (score 3):

Use Session at the head of your controller file

```
use Session;
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to import session Facade:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;
```

or you can use the class like this :

```
\Session::
```